# How can I check if a specific input type is checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two checkbox forms in my HTML-template, one of them allows multiple options and the other one only allows one option to be selected.

I am trying to limit the first checkbox form to only allow 2 boxes, but the current code affects both checkbox forms.

I can't use id or name since these are generated by the DB, id_something1, id_something2 etc.
How do people use to tackle this issue?

**Current JS**

```
<script>
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 2)) {
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
</script>
```

**The form I am trying to limit to 2 checkboxes**

```
<li class="list-group-item">
 <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <label>Test</label></label><input type="checkbox" name="orange" id="id_orange" checked>
 </div>
</li>

<li class="list-group-item">
 <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <label>Test2</label><input type="checkbox" name="banana" id="id_banana" checked>
 </div>
</li>
```

**Second form that also gets affected**

```
<ul id="id_someform">
 <li>
  <label for="id_someform_1"></label><input type="checkbox name="someForm" value=1" id="id_someform_1"
 </li>
 <li>
  <label for="id_someform_2"></label><input type="checkbox name="someForm" value=2" id="id_someform_2"
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are the `<form>` tags different or is it the same including both?

Comment: They are different! :)

Answer (score 1):

Limit the scope of your inner selector to the surrounding form:

```
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    const form = $(this).closest('form');

    if ( form.find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 2) ) {
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
```

Note that I've simplified your syntax with jQuery's `change()` method.

Comment: Sorry not that familiar with JQuery, should I use .closest('form_id') or is it literally the closest form in the HTML? If it's the closest it won't work since I have my JS at the bottom of the page, and the FORM in question is in the middle.

Comment: Don't use IDs in scripting unless you have to. They needlessly limit the reusability of your code. Here I'm looking for the form element that wraps the input that was changed.

Comment: Won't there be an issue since I use multiple forms in this page?

Comment: Hard to say. What you're calling "forms" in your question aren't forms. I really don't know what your situation looks like.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 2)) {
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
</script>
```

The above code snippet will listen for all checkbox events, instead, use different id property on your checkbox and change the selector to use the id of the checkbox you'd want to listen for the event, eg

```
<script>
  $('input#id_orange').on('change', function (e) {
    
    if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 2)) {
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This would require a function for each input, which isn't ideal.

Comment: Agree with @isherwood, but thanks for your input Karis

Answer (score 0):

If the form is different you can try replacing the following line:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
```

with:

```
$('#form-id input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
```

or:

```
$('form.class input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
```

or any other parent element that is different from one form to another.

For example:

```
$('#form-id input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function (e) {
    if ( $('#form-id input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 2 )  {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

I have tested it and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I replaced #form-id with my test ID but did not work

Comment: You need to replace `#form-id` in both the first and second line of the script.